# MySQL / PHP: catch all entries between 2 times and check against 2 other times

Tags: php, mysql, select, time, match

I have a database where people can book rooms within two certain times, but there may be other people searching for an available room within the same times - or partly in the same time.

Database looks like this:

```
order | room | user | date (date-format) | from (time) | to (time)
1       123    foo    2013-04-04           12:00:00       17:00:00
```

The problem comes when another user searches if the room is available from f.ex 13:00 to 18:00, since I only manage to search if the room is available in the exact same time.

The query has to search on specific room at a specific date, and a time aswell. If the room is busy in all, or some of the hours, I'd like to catch this and say to the user that the room is busy.

Any tips? If it's easier to manage through PHP I'd be glad too :-)

Comment: How do people search for rooms? Is there another table containing infos about the rooms? Will there be a row in the table you presented at all? Or will just the columns user, date, from and to be set to NULL?

Comment: I have a table containting the rooms (roomnames and roomtype). The roomname in "room"-table is identical to the entry in "booked" (as shown in example). People first choose a room and then check the availabilty against the "booked"-table in a certain time. All entries in the "booked"-database will have data (as shown in example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not solve it using SQL like this (untested):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM booked
WHERE
    room=$room AND
    date=$date AND
    (
        (
            /*
            The reservation starts in the requested period
            */    
            from <= $start_time AND
            to > $start_time
        ) OR (
            /*
            The reservation ends in the requested period
            */
            from < $end_time AND
            to >= $end_time
        )
    );
```

This query will return all reservations between `$start_time` and `$end_time` and allows reservations back to back. If you don't want to allow reservations back to back change the `<` and `>` to `<=` and `=>`.

**Important**: Make sure to not just use string interpolation and insert user-supplied input unescaped as it will leave your application vulnerable  to SQL-injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

An improvement on the answer by @Delphinator

```
SELECT *
FROM booked
WHERE
    room=$room AND
    date=$date AND
    (
       TIME("$start_time") BETWEEN from and to 
       OR
       TIME("$end_time") BETWEEN from and to
    );
```

`BETWEEN` does exactly what you would think.