# Same Result On Different Values of Time in mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql

```
    /*
    * Returns rows from the database based on the conditions
    * @param string name of the table
    * @param array select, where, order_by, limit and return_type conditions
    */

    public function getRows($table,$conditions = array()){
    $sql = 'SELECT ';
    $sql .= array_key_exists("select",$conditions)?$conditions['select']:'*';
    $sql .= ' FROM '.$table;
    if(array_key_exists("where",$conditions)){
        $sql .= ' WHERE ';
        $i = 0;
        foreach($conditions['where'] as $key => $value){
            $pre = ($i > 0)?' AND ':'';
            $sql .= $pre.$key." = '".$value."'";
            $i++;
        }
    }

    if(array_key_exists("order_by",$conditions)){
        $sql .= ' ORDER BY '.$conditions['order_by']; 
    }

    if(array_key_exists("start",$conditions) && array_key_exists("limit",$conditions)){
        $sql .= ' LIMIT '.$conditions['start'].','.$conditions['limit']; 
    }elseif(!array_key_exists("start",$conditions) && array_key_exists("limit",$conditions)){
        $sql .= ' LIMIT '.$conditions['limit']; 
    }


    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();

    if(array_key_exists("return_type",$conditions) && $conditions['return_type'] != 'all'){
        switch($conditions['return_type']){
            case 'count':
                $data = $query->rowCount();
                break;
            case 'single':
                $data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                break;
            default:
                $data = '';
        }
    }else{
        if($query->rowCount() > 0){
            $data = $query->fetchAll();
        }
    }
    return !empty($data)?$data:false;
}
```

Here is My Code by which i am getting Results

```
$con_date ='2017/01/28';
            $convenue='plaza';
            $constime='12:00';
            $conetime='13:00';


    $checkvenue=$crud->getRows('temp_requests',array('where'=>array('t_date'=>$con_date,'t_venue'=>$convenue,'t_stime<= '.$constime.',t_etime> '.$constime.' OR t_stime<'.$conetime.', t_etime>='.$conetime.'')));
```

Basically i want to make sure that neither same time venue exits or is not between any of the existing record.
I am Getting Same Result on Even Changing Above time values...Any Good is welcomed ..Thanks

[Reference For Condition i want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807516/mysql-php-catch-all-entries-between-2-times-and-check-against-2-other-times)

Comment: What is that function good for? And what is your question?

Comment: I am changing values of above variables but still the condition the returning same results

Comment: i just want to that this condition syntax with respect to above method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807516/mysql-php-catch-all-entries-between-2-times-and-check-against-2-other-times